# lstat() st_blocks outputting incorrect value

Tags: c, struct, stat

Whenever I run my program for every directory 8 is output even when I use ls-ls to check the actual size of each directory.
Im trying to print the st_blocks of all the directories the user enters

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{

  struct stat path_stat;
  int i;
  int size=0;
  for (i=1; i <argc; i++){
      if (lstat(argv[i], &path_stat)) {
          perror(argv[i]);
      } else {

          if (S_ISDIR(path_stat.st_mode)){
            size=path_stat.st_blocks;
             printf("%d  %s \n",size,argv[i]);
          }

      }
  }
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the output 8 is wrong?

Comment: I've checked it using numerous directories and used ls -ls to to double check

Comment: `ls -ls` cannot possibly show you the size of the directory. It does not even list the directory but rather the files inside it.

Comment: it can show the number of blocks allocated to the file and I just have to add all the numbers up and I believe I should be getting the same results if I just got the st_blocks please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: You're wrong. The size of the files linked in a directory has nothing to do with the size of the directory. To see the size of the directory, use `ls -lsd dirname`.

Comment: Regardless I want to know why I'm getting 8

Comment: What is `st_blksize`? Actually I don't think it's relevant. `st_blocks` is normally in units of 512 bytes, so 8 blocks means 4k which is the typical fs allocation unit.

Comment: Thats not what I'm suppose to use

Comment: It might help to answer your question, if you include in your post what exactly you are looking to achieve.  As these comments suggest, it looks like you are [trying to solve the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Answer (score 2):

st_blocks is the number of 512 byte blocks allocated to the directory node. 8x512 = 4096 bytes = 1 block for a typical modern filesystem seems correct.

It will not tell you the total size of files within the folder or similar information, if that is what you are hoping to obtain.

For more information:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/186813/why-does-every-directory-have-a-size-4096-bytes-4-k